# I want to add dynamic image view on relation layout at touch point

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add dynamic image view on touch location at relative layout.
I'm able to add image view but not at exact location.

Actually when I'm adding image view, I'm seeing in layout bounds a small square area at the left top corner on relative layout.

Please see these images.

[image]

[image]

Here is my code.

```
public class ActivityIHMSurvey extends AppCompatActivity{

private Button btnSurveyList;
private ImageView imgBase;
private RelativeLayout baseLayout;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private String imageName, imageFilePath;
private CustomGallery mCustomGallery;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ihm_survey);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("IHM Survey Screen");
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    btnSurveyList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_survey_list);
    baseLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.base_layout);
    imgBase = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_base);
    imgBase.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListenerClass());

    Intent bundleIntent = getIntent();
    if (bundleIntent.hasExtra("imageData"))
        mCustomGallery = (CustomGallery) bundleIntent
                .getSerializableExtra("imageData");
    btnSurveyList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    initImageLoader();
    setImageData(mCustomGallery);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void initImageLoader() {
    try {
        String CACHE_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/.temp_tmp";
        new File(CACHE_DIR).mkdirs();

        File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(
                getApplicationContext(), CACHE_DIR);

        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisc(true).imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
        ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                getApplicationContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache());

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = builder.build();
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

private void setImageData(CustomGallery imageData) {
    if (imageData != null) {

        imageName = imageData.getImageName();
        imageFilePath = imageData.getSdcardPath();

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("IHM Survey Screen - " + imageName);
        try {

            imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + imageData.getSdcardPath(),
                    imgBase, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri,
                                View view) {
                            imgBase.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_media);
                            super.onLoadingStarted(imageUri, view);
                        }
                    });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            calculateImageView(imgBase);
        }
    }, 2000);
}

private void calculateImageView(ImageView imgBase){
    int x = (int) imgBase.getX();
    int y = (int) imgBase.getY();
    int xw = imgBase.getWidth();
    int yw = imgBase.getHeight();
    Log.e("","x"+x+"y"+y+"xw"+xw+"yw"+yw);
}

public void addMarker(int positionX,int positionY, int rawX, int rawY) {

    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis();

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.marker);
    imgView.setTag(tsLong);
    imgView.setX(positionX);
    imgView.setY(positionY);
    imgView.setLayoutParams(imParams);
    baseLayout.addView(imgView);
    alertDialog(imgView);
    imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            markerClickListener(v);             
        }
    });
}

public void alertDialog(final ImageView v){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityIHMSurvey.this)
    .setTitle("Confirm entry")
    .setMessage("Are you sure to add mark here?")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

            baseLayout.removeView((View)v);

        }
     })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
     .show();
}

public void markerClickListener(View v){
    Log.e("",
            "id:"+v.getTag());
    baseLayout.removeView(v);
}

public class TouchListenerClass implements OnTouchListener{

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.e("",
                    "rawX:" + event.getRawX() + " rawY:" + event.getRawY());
            addMarker((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY(), (int)event.getRawX(),(int)event.getRawY());
            break;
        }
        return true;

    }

}
```

}

Here is Xml code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/base_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_survey_list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar" 
    android:background="@color/black_semi_transparent2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_base"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/tsc_image"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_survey_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_20"
    android:text="@string/btn_show_list_text" />
```

Please help me out to remove small square area space.

Comment: Sorry I may be misunderstanding, can you clarify a bit. The marker shows up to the left of the island in the image, but there is a box in the top left? Where is everything supposed to go?

Answer (score 1):

You can user `setTranslationX` and `setTranslationY` for that:

```
    final RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
    container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                View marker = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.marker, container, false);
                marker.setTranslationX(event.getX());
                marker.setTranslationY(event.getY());
                container.addView(marker);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

I hope, it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but currently I'm using Layout margin to set layout at right touch position.

Answer (score 0):

In addMarker method,I'm using LayoutParams of marker ImageView to add image at right place.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ImageView imgView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    imgView.setTag(timeStampId);
    lp.setMargins(positionX + startBaseImageX, positionY + startBaseImageY,
            0, 0);
    imgView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```